# How did I solve this problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relation-algebra

While writing a SQL query I had to solve a problem I'd never dealt with before. It was trivial, but I cannot explain the solution without drawing lines on paper or making examples with actual numbers - and I don't like it: I want to give a rigorous answer and I want to learn about this subject.

**The problem**

- There are objects with `starts_on` and `expires_on` properties (SQL type `DATE`), `starts_on` must be less or equal to `expires_on`.
- We say the object is *active at date D* if `starts_on ≤ D ≤ expires_on`
- We say the object is *active in the range* of dates R(range_start, range_end) if it's active in at least one date D, `range_start ≤ D ≤ range_end`
- It turns out that the final where clause is `starts_on ≤ range_end AND expires_on ≥ range_start`

How do mathematicians solve this problem? How can I explain where my SQL comes from without any fancy painting? I think the starting point may be the function:

```
active_at_date = f(starts_on, expires_on, target_date)
```

which returns:

- TRUE, if `starts_on ≤ target_date ≤ expires_on`
- FALSE otherwise

But then, how could I go on?

<sub>Hope my question is not offtopic here. I worded it as best as I can, but it's the first attempt on this stackexchange site (and my math knowledge is very limited in this context, I know)</sub>

Comment: well SQL is fundamentally based on set theory. hopefully you'll get an answer here, but there are also plenty of textbooks on relational databases which go into the set theory side of it.

Comment: @TooTone my main problem is I don't know how these things **are called**, so cannot start a search by myself :) Hope someone can point me in the right direction. SQL is based on set theory (that's how I tagged my question), but I think the problem here is combining predicates, so maybe more a differential calculus one - really don't know where to start

Comment: ok are you happy with an answer that focusses on pointing you in the right direction on the relationship between SQL and set theory?

Comment: @TooTone Hope so! Don't want others to do my job for me for free, just a help to jump the wall I hit, so I'll be able to keep running on my own. Of course, an answer like *SQL is based on set theory and this is a dozen of good books...* isn't going to help that much - something like *Short explanation is [...] This subject is called X and I found R to be a really helpful resource when learning* would do

Comment: I guess `ends_on` means `expires_on`? Because you don't explain what `ends_on` means.

Comment: @frabala you're right. I'll fix the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some object, and let $A$ be the set of its active dates. Also, let $R$ be some range we would want to check. The check itself is $R \cap A \neq \varnothing$, or in other words, there exists $d$ such that $d \in R$ and $d \in A$.

Now, we know, that $A$ and $R$ are not just any sets, but intervals, i.e. $A = [a_\min,a_\max]$ and $R = [r_\min,r_\max]$. Using this property we can simplify our query.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose, there exists a date $d \in R \cap A$. Then,

\begin{align}
a_\min \leq &d \leq a_\max & \text{ because } d \in A, \tag{1}\\
r_\min \leq &d \leq r_\max & \text{ because } d \in R, \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
however, by mixing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
\begin{align}
a_\min \leq &d \leq r_\max \\
r_\min \leq &d \leq a_\max
\end{align}
which simplifies to exactly what we need. Therefore, this condition is necessary. Is it sufficient?

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let's assume that
$$a_\min \leq r_\max \quad \land \quad r_\min \leq a_\max. \tag{3}$$
Set
\begin{align}
b_\min &= \max(a_\min,r_\min), \\
b_\max &= \min(a_\max,r_\max),
\end{align}
and observe, that by $3$ we have $$b_\min \leq b_\max.\tag{4}$$ Now, suppose that there exists $d \in [b_\min, b_\max]$, then $r_\min \leq d \leq r_\max$ so $d \in R$ and analogously $d \in A$. Hence, $d \in R \cap A$. The question is, whether range $[b_\min,b_\max]$ is non-empty, but this is implied by $(4)$, namely both $b_\min$ and $b_\max$ could substitute for $d$. This implies that the condition is sufficient.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: The beauty of this answer is that it's so exact, yet so simple, that I read it and then thought "*Why didn't I think of it before?*". Beside, you have been the only one to prove what others called "mixing" or "combination of predicates", so I think you deserved your +25 :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's rephrase your problem:

- The  `starts_on` and `expires_on` attributes form a closed time interval $[a,b]$.
- The object is active at time D, if $D \in [a,b]$.
- A range of dates is another interval, say $[c,d]$.
- The object is active in $[c,d]$ when any D of $[a,b]$ is also in $[c,d]$, in other words: the interval overlap: $[a,b]\cap [c,d] \neq \emptyset$.

Therefore some existing $D$ must fullfil the requirements

- $a \leq D \leq b$ and
- $c \leq D \leq d$.

Combined these requirements give $a \leq d$ and $c \leq b$.

P.S. There is nothing wrong with a case analysis given by drawing timelines ("one picture save 1k words"):

```
 a  b 
 ---- no                   ---- no 
 ------- yes --- yes  ------  yes  
      -------------------- yes     
       |----------------|       
       c                d
```

Comment: +1, loved the wording at the beginning. I accepted @dtldarek's because my main point was explaining the *combination of the requirements* part without depicting it

Comment: @Raffaele: I have to admit, I'm a physicist and programmer, so I'm more interested in a solid, but quick problem solution. I'm completely satisfied with your decision, there is beauty in dtldarek's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution comes from the definitions: You write

> We say the object is active in the range of dates `R(range_start, range_end)` if it's active in at least one date D, `range_start ≤ D ≤ range_end`

But for the object to be active in at least one date D, it is necessary that `starts_on ≤ D ≤ expires_on`. This is because of the definition you gave:

> We say the object is active at date D if `starts_on ≤ D ≤ expires_on`

So, you have two double inequalities that have to hold for D:

> `range_start ≤ D ≤ range_end`
>
> `starts_on ≤ D ≤ expires_on`

Now, if you "mix" them, you get `range_start ≤ expires_on` and `starts_on ≤ range_end`.

Comment: Upvoted. Accepted @dtldarek's answer because my main concern was explaining what you call the "mixing"

Comment: @Raffaele Fair enough :)